# Find out what is this binary database entry and what format it is

Tags: binary-analysis, decompilation, decryption, binary-format, binary-diagnosis

the following varbinary "BUFFER" of a database entry is for an article.

FIELD_0 is in plain text and the item name is "1", which I created with the item management software.

```
[FIELD_0]    NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL
[BUFFER]     VARBINARY(8000) NOT NULL
```

```
[
  {
    "FIELD_0": "1",
    "BUFFER": "0x02789C535050D0F636500102024320D60E8904311D8158372A1CC4740D0D02891714803846206684215CB51342639431886901021635833303DCE1CC2813B80951060851238436538428D80A0301022C611A07"
  }
]
```

Article price 1,00 EUR:

```
0x02789C535050D0F636500102024320D60E8904311D8158372A1CC4740D0D02891714803846206684215CB51342639431886901021635833303DCE1CC2813845A0384A811429B2942146C85010301022C341A06
```

Article price 2,00 EUR:

```
0x02789C535050D0F636500102024320D60E8904311D8158372A1CC4740D0D02891714803846206684215CB51342639431886901021635833303DCE1CC2813B80951060851238436538428D80A0301022C611A07
```

Article price removed:

```
0x02789C535050D0F636500102024320D60E8904311D8158372A1CC4740D0D02891714803846206684215CB51342639431886901021635833303DCE1CC280304D308A1D614216A88609A809901022AA71A05
```

after creating the item without changing any values (price, etc.)

```
0x02789C535050D0F636500102024320D60E8904311D8158372A1CC4740D0D02891714803846206684215CB51342631458D40102CC3440308D104C6304D304CC040102268114CE
```

I can't find out at this time what format is behind BUFFER. The database is an MS-SQL database and I suspect that the entry may have been compressed before storing as `varbinary` or something like that.

Maybe someone has an idea how the entry was created.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Do you have access to the item management software? .. that would be easier than looking for patterns in the bytes. Even looking through their documentation might be enlightening.

Comment: Yes, I have access to the management software. Unfortunately there is no documentation on the database structure or the respective entries. Apparently there is an ODBC driver, but it is hidden behind a paywall and therefore I think the more that the entries are encrypted, xored or similar.

I already thought about evaluating the data traffic between GUI and MS-SQL database.

Comment: Good idea, at some point the data has to be decoded/extracted for viewing and I don't think that will be a database function.